# Cannot read property 'setState' of null react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, single-page-application, typeerror, arrow-functions

This code was given to me while answering another question, it works fine in `Codepen`. [Original code](http://codepen.io/dagman/pen/gwzBjX?editors=1010)

However when I try adapting it to my project, first of all, the arrow function is not recognized and I get the Unexpected token error at this arrow function:

```
getBtnId = (e) => {
    //code in here
};
```

So I changed it to a regular function, and now the component looks like this:

```
export default class HelpPage extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        panelIndex: 0
    };
    this.getBtnId.bind(this);
}

getBtnId (e) {
    if(e.target && e.target.nodeName == "BUTTON") {
        console.log(e.target);
        this.setState({
            panelIndex: Number(e.target.id)
        });
  }
  return e;
};

render() {
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <HelpMenu
                getBtnId={this.getBtnId}
            />
            <HelpPanels
                panelIndex={this.state.panelIndex}
            />
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

However now whenever I press one of the buttons I get the error

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of null"

What can I do now to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually `this.getBtnId.bind(this)` do nothing !

This will solve your problem :

```
this.getBtnId = this.getBtnId.bind(this);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your error is coming from inside getBtnId(). The "this" keyword is not available inside event handlers without specifically passing it through.

The standard way to achieve this is to use 'bind' when connecting your function to the component's event:

```
<HelpMenu
  getBtnId={this.getBtnId.bind(this)}
/>
```